# Can not identify the object in QTP

Tags: qtp

I'm using QTP 9.2. While running script i got this error repeatedly

> Cannot identify the object "Login1$Password" (of class WebEdit).
>   Verify that this object's properties match an object currently
>   displayed in your application.

When i run the script for first time it runs perfectly but now this error occurred. I have tried all the possible solution check object properties through object repository and object spy and enable smart identification result shows:

> object not unique (3 objects found) or object not found..

Answer (score 0):

Open the object repository and look at the properties that describe the test object. 
Now use the object spy to see the values of the same properties on the `WebEdit` that is displayed in your application. You should find a mismatch, now you have to decide if the new values are what you expect to see (in which case you can use the **update from application** button) or if both values are acceptable (in which case you should change the values of the properties to regular expression to cover all acceptable cases).

Comment: there is no mismatch in the properties and i already have changes the values to regular expression

Comment: @user1194112 some things to try: check that the parent is identified OK, try to add an ordinal identifier (`index=0`)

Comment: still got this error i have added ordinal identifier..any other way to resolve it?

Comment: yes i have tried but can not identify object error appeared again

Comment: update from application solve the problem but warnings are still there that is 'The object was not found using the test object description. Check the object's properties'

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some changes has happen for that object either in Application or Object repository. So you better update the object description for that object in the object repository using the option "Update from Application".

Thanks,
GD

Answer (score 0):

I don't have QTP 9.2 so I'm not quite sure if this is valid, but can't you add a visual identifier for the object?

If the object position never changes and there is another mapped object close to it that also never changes position, you could use this second object as a relation to the one your are trying to map.

In UFT 12 this option is called **Visual relation identifier settings** and is located in Object Properties, below Description Properties list. From that, you can either select a mapped object from your repository, or add a new one, from the screen. After that you can determine the relation between the objects (above/below, left/right, inline or not).

If none of the options provided by me and others work and if you have access to development team, I'd suggest requesting them to provide an ID for the object.

Also, as a good practice, I'd disable the Smart Identification feature, as it can sometimes mess up the object identification