# Description mismatch in QTP

Tags: qtp

Im using QTP 9.2
Test result generates warning:
The object was not found using the test object description. Check the object's properties.
The smart identification mechanism was invoked.

Reason: object not found.
how to resolve with this warning? I am new to QTP

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can not identify the object in QTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172731/can-not-identify-the-object-in-qtp)

Answer (score 1):

**resources --> Object Repository --> select the element that caused exception --> in the description (present in right panel inside object repository)--> delete the properties present in the description**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co0f4.jpg)

When I used innertext to retrive test it happened. because the value of innertext is dynamic and changes every time. the text object property value in Object repository and runtime object inner text value mismatched. so exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, there is no enough information, for QTP to find the object.
Try to add new properties to the object, or update it from the application to get updated properties.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the the object is created at run time (ie, if the parameters for the object vary from run to run for some unknown reason), you may also find using Descriptive Programming, rather than the Object Repository beneficial. A bit of googling will soon have you using descriptive programming nicely...